# FFmpegFrameGrabber.start() crashes when loading mp4 file

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm trying to load a mp4 video file I record somewhere else in the app, and then want to pass the image's address to a jni native opencv code to do some processing.

```
FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber;

            grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(videoPath);
            grabber.start();
            grabber.getFrameNumber();
            grabber.getLengthInTime();
            grabber.getLengthInFrames();

            frameRate = grabber.getFrameRate();

            Log.d("V1", "FRAME RATE = " + frameRate);

            grabber.stop();
            grabber.release();
```

It show `Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.v1.v1golf2-rWziofbEW92JsJ7hvlJj5g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.v1.v1golf2-rWziofbEW92JsJ7hvlJj5g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.v1.v1golf2-rWziofbEW92JsJ7hvlJj5g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libjniavutil.so"` error.

Dependency which I am using below :-

```
implementation 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv-platform:3.1.0-1.3'
    implementation 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg-platform:3.2.1-1.3'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're building the application for the `arm64` architecture but you're missing the native ffmpeg libraries for `arm64`. If you want to support 64-bit you have to update your ffmpeg-platform dependency to a version that offers 64-bit builds. See the 4.x versions on http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/ which have `android-arm64` jars.